# local server with gulp browsersync is unable to load my javascript file?

Tags: javascript, python, gulp, browser-sync

I tried to start a server with *gulp browsersync*. I was expecting to show all my folders and files from the source file like *python-m simplehttpserver*,  but it open only my *index.html* and I can see other files and most importantly the *javascirpt* file in the *index.html* is not loading. The error is "the file not found error 404".

The same file load JS file when I use python localserver.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
browserSync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: "./src"
    }
});
});
```